# django: django-taggit usage

Tags: django, django-tagging, django-taggit

This is probably a stupid question but I downloaded `Django-taggit` and the docs mentioned  adding a `TaggableManager`manager to the each model I want to associate. This is fine, but what about models from external apps I "pip-ed"? What's the best way to use taggit with these models?

Answer (score 2):

You could subclass the model in the external app in one of your own apps, that would probably be a reasonable solution, i.e.

```
from someapp.models import SomeModel
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class SomeModelTagged(SomeModel):
    tags = TaggableManager()
```

Then in the views where you used SomeModel from the external app you would have to use your new model instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily register model from any of your external apps with taggit. Assume the name of the model is Item.

```
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager
from external_app.models import Item

Item.add_to_class('tags', TaggableManager())
```

And then you can use taggit in usual way.

```
i = Item.objects.get(pk=1)
i.tags.add("wassup")
i.tags.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have pip install the editable version with (-e VCS+REPOS_URL[@REV]#egg=PACKAGE) and add the django-taggable integration yourself.

Comment: I'm guessing he wants to avoid just that. With django-taggi*ng* you can register the model but I haven't tested whether you can do the registering outside of the app to be registered.